# How to access the id of an inputId created on the server?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, r

I have an application that, when I add 10 to the `sliderInput`, an "OK" button appears. But, its `inputId` is not accessible in the DOM because `#sbtn1` was created in the `server`. And I need it because of my need in the app.

I would like to access this `inputId` (`#sbtn1`) to modify it via `JS` (`file.js`) but it doesn't exist.

My app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  
  title = "Dashboard", 
  titleWidth = 300, 
  
  dropdownMenuOutput(
    outputId = "drop1"
  )
  
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  
  width = 300
  
)

jscode <- "$(function() {
  $('.skin-blue').addClass('sidebar-mini');
});
"

body <- dashboardBody(

  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = "JS"),
  
  sliderInput(
    inputId = "one", 
    label = "Registro 1", 
    value = 1, 
    animate = animationOptions(
      interval = 500, loop = TRUE
    ),  
    min = 1, 
    max = 10, 
    step = 1, 
    ticks = TRUE
  ), 
  
  sliderInput(
    inputId = "two",
    label = "Registro 2", 
    value = 1, 
    animate = animationOptions(
      interval = 500, loop = TRUE
    ),  
    min = 1, 
    max = 10, 
    step = 1, 
    ticks = TRUE
  ),
  
  valueBoxOutput(
    outputId = "box1"
  )
  
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  header = header, 
  sidebar = sidebar, 
  body = body
  
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  fsoma <- function(x) {
    if (x != 10) {
      "Error!"
      
    } else
      (actionButton(
        inputId = "sbtn1",
        label = "OK",
        icon = icon("play-circle-o"),
        style = "color: #f2f2f2; background-color: #333333;
      border-color: #333333;"
      ))
    
  }
  
  fx <- function(x, y) {
    
    x + y
    
  }
  
  fy <- function(x) {
    
    x
    
  }
  
  reac_0 <- reactive({
    
    tibble::tibble(
      one = input$one, 
      two = input$two, 
      three = input$three
    )
    
  })
  
  chuveiro <- reactive({
    
    temp <- reac_0()
    fx(
      x = temp$one, 
      y = temp$two
    )
    
  })
  
  luz <- reactive({
    
    temp <- reac_0()
    fy(
      x = temp$three
    )
    
  })
  
  output$box1 <- renderValueBox({
    
    expr = valueBox(
      value = fsoma(x = chuveiro()), 
      subtitle = "Sum"
    )
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

How do I access this id (`#sbtn1`) to handle it in my `file.js` document?

Comment: I don't understand when you have the OK displayed, then you have the `#sbtn1` in the DOM. What's the problem?

Comment: Hello. If you create a `file.js` and use some code, something like: `$(function() {

$("#sbtn1").css("background-color", "red");

});`

you will see that the effect on `#sbtn1` will not be applied.

Comment: Of course, you won't see it.  the button is created later than you run the js. You need to bind the button with the script by either executing it after button creation or add a listener to watch for the display change.

Comment: How can I do this? I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Please edit the code on how you apply the javascript, we can fix it from there.

Comment: I edited my code adding the `JS` in the `shinyjs` context. As an example, I added the `sidebar-mini` class to the app's sidebar. It works normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bind the script after the button, so the script runs every time after the button is created.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(
    title = "Dashboard", 
    titleWidth = 300, 
    dropdownMenuOutput(
        outputId = "drop1"
    )
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    width = 300
)


body <- dashboardBody(
    sliderInput(
        inputId = "one", 
        label = "Registro 1", 
        value = 1, 
        animate = animationOptions(
            interval = 500, loop = TRUE
        ),  
        min = 1, 
        max = 10, 
        step = 1, 
        ticks = TRUE
    ), 
    
    sliderInput(
        inputId = "two",
        label = "Registro 2", 
        value = 1, 
        animate = animationOptions(
            interval = 500, loop = TRUE
        ),  
        min = 1, 
        max = 10, 
        step = 1, 
        ticks = TRUE
    ),
    
    valueBoxOutput(
        outputId = "box1"
    )
    
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    
    header = header, 
    sidebar = sidebar, 
    body = body
    
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
    fsoma <- function(x) {
        if (x != 10) {
            "Error!"
        } else {
            div(
                actionButton(
                    inputId = "sbtn1",
                    label = "OK",
                    icon = icon("play-circle-o"),
                    style = "color: #f2f2f2; background-color: #333333; border-color: #333333;"
                ),
                tags$script('$(function() {console.log(1); $("#sbtn1").css("background-color", "red");})')
            )
        }
    }
    
    fx <- function(x, y){ x + y}
    
    fy <- function(x){x}
    
    reac_0 <- reactive({
        tibble::tibble(
            one = input$one, 
            two = input$two, 
            three = input$three
        )
    })
    
    chuveiro <- reactive({
        temp <- reac_0()
        fx(
            x = temp$one, 
            y = temp$two
        )
    })
    
    luz <- reactive({
        temp <- reac_0()
        fy(
            x = temp$three
        )
        
    })
    
    output$box1 <- renderValueBox({
        valueBox(
            value = fsoma(x = chuveiro()), 
            subtitle = "Sum"
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]